# NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 5.0 Visual Profiler "Enable concurrent kernels profiling" application requirements

Tags: opencv, cuda, nvidia

OS: Windows 7 64 bit 
Compiler: Visual Studio 2010 Professional 
Driver: 306.23
Device: GeForce GTX 680 or GeForce GT 650M
I'm using CUDA Toolkit 5.0 because I need to use the new feature of the NVIDIA Visual Profiler of this Toolkit that allows to view in the timeline concurrent kernels executed asynchronously (this is not possible with the CUDA Toolkit 4.2). For this reason, I built (succesfully) the source code of OpenCV 2.4.2 with this Toolkit (5.0) installed on my pc (this was suggested to me on the OpenCV blog), and I'm able to compile and execute correctly my application with concurrent kernels: some of them are invoked by functions of the module OpenCV_GPU and others are kernels I directly wrote in CUDA. 
Unfortunately, CUDA 5.0 NVIDIA Visual Profiler can't trace the timeline of my application if I enable the feature: "Enable concurrent kernels profiling". 
It creates the timeline correctly both for code written using ONLY OpenCV functions and for code written using ONLY CUDA functions. Indeed, it stops working when I mix the two in the same application . 
I think this may be caused by the fact that OpenCV calls should use the same CUDA Context as the rest of the CUDA code. 
How can I manage the CUDA Context in order to allow the Profiler to trace the timeline?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please add driver version, device information, and a reproducible. If you cannot provide a full reproducible list the functions you are calling. Thanks.

Comment: I modified the question refining the problem and adding the information you asked. I'm workng to provide also a peace of code if it's stil useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. I have sent the issue to the CUDA Visual Profiler development team. We will try to reproduce the problem based upon your updated information.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I answered my own question after experimenting and analyzing the code line by line. I believed it was a problem of the Profiler because Visual Studio didn't notice me about 'out-of-memory' problems, nor the Profiler, it rather traced the application when not in "Concurrent kernel profiling" modality. Then, by chance, I reduced the number of stream by only one unit and everything was ok, so I realized. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Well, trying to solve my problem, I experimented that it was not a problem of CUDA Context: applications written using both CUDA and OpenCV are traced well by the Profiler. Instead, it was a problem of memory: simply, in the application that contains both the CUDA version and the OpenCV version of my algorithm, I use a number of streams that is twice the size of that I use in the applications with only one version of the algorithm, and this exceeds the memory capacity of the Profiler. I thought that it was a problem of the Profiler besause the application with the two methods runs correctly, and it only stops when I run it from the Profiler in the "Enable concurrent kernels execution" modality to trace the timeline. This must be explained by the fact that the Profiler uses much more memory to trace the timeline in this modality, so the limit of the number of streams is lower than in the synchronous modalitiy. However, I am a beginner, so I'd better not advance hypotheses riskly. I solved it out using fewer streams. I apologize for the misleading question.

Comment: The Nsight VSE CUDA Profiler and the Visual Profiler track work per stream. This requires a pool of device memory to be allocate for each stream. These pools are small compared to the total available memory on most devices. How many streams were you allocating?

Comment: I need to allocate at least 32 streams (and this number is well supported by the Profiler). Anyway, I have experenced that more than 56 streams are not supported by the Profiler, is it plausible? Is this number dipending from the operations issued to the streams or is it strictly related only to the number of streams allocated?  The application executes correctly even with more streams, the problems of memory arise with the Profiler only in the "Enable conc kernel profiling" modality. Is there a way to tell the Profiler to reserve more pools of memory if one needs to profile more streams?